# how to solve this java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.#######?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

Again am having the problem with the same thing while calling one add function with the other custom portlet.
i have one method in my portlet class with addrestaurant(restaurant) and when i call that from my view to add the data its giving me following error.

```
05:27:42,752 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-4][render_portlet_jsp:154] java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.addrestaurant(javax.portlet.ActionRequest, javax.portlet.ActionResponse)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.MethodCache._get(MethodCache.java:123)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.MethodCache.get(MethodCache.java:45)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.callActionMethod(LiferayPortlet.java:149)
    at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.callActionMethod(MVCPortlet.java:250)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.LiferayPortlet.processAction(LiferayPortlet.java:80)
    at com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.processAction(MVCPortlet.java:220)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:70)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
```

i had check all things but still no reason i found that why this happening..dont know everytime its coming when i create new portlet..

following is my restaurantportlet.java class

```
public class RestaurantPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(RestaurantPortlet.class);
    private static String errorJSP="/jsps/error.jsp" ;

    public void addrestaurant(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {

        log.info("Inside addRegistration");
        List<String> errors=new ArrayList<String>();


        restaurant rest=RestaurantActionUtil.getRestaurantFromRequest(request);
        boolean bookValid=RestaurantValidator.validateRestaurant(rest,errors);
        if(bookValid) {
            try {
                log.info(rest);
                restaurant test=restaurantLocalServiceUtil.addrestaurant(rest);
                if(test==null) {
                    log.error("Restaurant was Found Null");
                    response.setRenderParameter("jspPage", errorJSP);
                    return ;
                }
            } catch (SystemException e) {
                log.error(e);
                /*If there is an error then divert the control to the error page.*/
                response.setRenderParameter("jspPage", errorJSP);
                return ;
            }
            SessionMessages.add(request,"restaurant-added");
            return ;
        }
        else {
             for (String error : errors) {
                    SessionErrors.add(request, error);
                }
                SessionErrors.add(request, "error-while-adding");
                request.setAttribute("rest",rest);
                return ;
        }

    }
```

following is my restaurantImpl.java class

```
 */
public class restaurantLocalServiceImpl extends restaurantLocalServiceBaseImpl {
    /*
     * NOTE FOR DEVELOPERS:
     *
     * Never reference this interface directly. Always use {@link emenu.advertise.database.service.restaurantLocalServiceUtil} to access the restaurant local service.
     */
    public restaurant addrestaurant(restaurant restParam) {
        restaurant restVar;

        try {
            restVar = restaurantPersistence.create(counterLocalService
                    .increment(advertise.class.toString()));
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return restVar = null;
        }

        try {
            resourceLocalService.addResources(restParam.getGroupId(), restParam.getUserId(),
                    advertise.class.getName(), false);
        } catch (PortalException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return restVar = null;
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return restVar = null;
        }

        restVar.setName(restParam.getName());
        restVar.setAdress(restParam.getAdress());
        restVar.setCity(restParam.getCity());
        restVar.setPin(restParam.getPin());
        restVar.setState(restParam.getState());
        restVar.setCountry(restParam.getCountry());
        restVar.setContactno(restParam.getContactno());
        restVar.setEmail(restParam.getEmail());
        restVar.setWebsite(restParam.getWebsite());
        restVar.setCuisinetype(restParam.getCuisinetype());
        restVar.setPersonalmail(restParam.getPersonalmail());
        restVar.setPersonalname(restParam.getPersonalname());
        restVar.setPersonalPhone(restParam.getPersonalPhone());
        restVar.setNoofemenuagent(restParam.getNoofemenuagent());
        restVar.setLicensekey(restParam.getLicensekey());
        restVar.setRestregId(restParam.getRestId());
        restVar.setNoofdiningtable(restParam.getNoofdiningtable());
        restVar.setAvgnoofcustomermonthly(restParam.getAvgnoofcustomermonthly());
        restVar.setAveragroupagevisit(restParam.getAveragroupagevisit());
        restVar.setImpoflocation(restParam.getImpoflocation());
        restVar.setAvgmonthlycheckamount(restParam.getAvgmonthlycheckamount());
        restVar.setCostperthousandimpression(restParam.getCostperthousandimpression());
        restVar.setAdtypeId(restParam.getAdtypeId());
        //restVar.setNoofdiningtable(restParam.getNoofdiningtable());
        //restVar.setAvgnoofcustomermonthly(restParam.getAvgnoofcustomermonthly());


        restVar.setIsactive(restParam.getIsactive());
        restVar.setCreateddate(restParam.getCreateddate());
        restVar.setLastmodifiedby(restParam.getLastmodifiedby());
        restVar.setModifieddate(restParam.getModifieddate());
        restVar.setGroupId(restParam.getGroupId());
        restVar.setUserId(restParam.getUserId());
        restVar.setIsdeleted(restParam.getIsdeleted());
        restVar.setRestregId(restParam.getRestregId());

        //restVar.setOrganizationId(restParam.getOrganizationId());

        try {
            return restaurantPersistence.update(restVar, false);
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return restVar = null;
        }
    }
```

following is My restuarntActionutil class

```
public class RestaurantActionUtil {



        public static restaurant getRestaurantFromRequest(ActionRequest request) {
            ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request
                    .getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
            String name = ParamUtil.getString(request, "name",
                    "name Not Availible");
                    restaurant rest  = new restaurantImpl();
            rest.setName(name);
            rest.setLicensekey(ParamUtil.getString(request, "licesnce_key"));
            rest.setCity(ParamUtil.getString(request, "city"));
            rest.setPin(ParamUtil.getString(request, "pin"));
            rest.setAdress(ParamUtil.getString(request, "adress"));
            rest.setState(ParamUtil.getString(request, "state"));
            rest.setCountry(ParamUtil.getString(request, "country"));
            rest.setContactno(ParamUtil.getString(request, "contact_no"));
            rest.setEmail(ParamUtil.getString(request, "email"));
            rest.setWebsite(ParamUtil.getString(request, "website"));
            rest.setCuisinetype(ParamUtil.getString(request, "cuisine_type"));
            rest.setNoofemenuagent(ParamUtil.getInteger(request, "no_of_emenu_agent"));
            rest.setNoofdiningtable(ParamUtil.getInteger(request, "no_of_dining_table"));
            rest.setPersonalname(ParamUtil.getString(request, "personal_name"));
            rest.setPersonalPhone(ParamUtil.getString(request, "personal_phone"));
            rest.setPersonalmail(ParamUtil.getString(request, "personal_mail"));
            rest.setAveragroupagevisit(ParamUtil.getInteger(request, "avg_age_group_people"));
            rest.setImpoflocation(ParamUtil.getString(request, "imp_of_location"));
            rest.setAvgnoofcustomermonthly(ParamUtil.getInteger(request, "avg_no_of_cust_monthly"));
            rest.setAvgmonthlycheckamount(ParamUtil.getInteger(request, "avg_monthly_check_amount"));
            rest.setAvgmonthlycheckamount(ParamUtil.getLong(request, "cost_per_thousand_impressions"));
            rest.setAdtypeId(ParamUtil.getInteger(request, "ad_type"));
            rest.setIsactive(ParamUtil.getBoolean(request, "isactive"));
            rest.setGroupId(themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroupId());
            rest.setUserId(themeDisplay.getUserId());
            rest.setCreateddate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            rest.setModifieddate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            rest.setLastmodifiedby(themeDisplay.getUserId());
            rest.setRestregId((ParamUtil.getLong(request, "licensekey")));
            rest.setIsdeleted(false);



                        return rest;
        }


    }
```

following is my view.jsp code from which this method is called..

```
<liferay-portlet:actionURL name="addrestaurant" var="addrestoURL"></liferay-portlet:actionURL>

                      <form class="form_validation_ttip" action="<%= addrestoURL.toString()%>" method="post">
```

this is my button in form.

```
<button class="btn" name="btnback" >Save</button>
```

please anyone can guide me ??i need to find the main reason behind this..so from next time i will keep in mind about where am doing mistake..

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your `portlet.xml` here?
It looks like you did not specify your class, so Liferay tried to use the default MVCPortlet class. And of course, there is no `addrestaurant()` method.
It is not a code problem but a configuration problem.